# java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot initialize effect engine for type: 0bed4300-ddd6-11db-8f34-0002a5d5c51b Error: -3

Tags: android, runtimeexception

I am getting the following error in my equalizer app on Android MarshMellow, OnePlus.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.my.app.name/com.my.app.name.activity.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot initialize effect engine for type: 0bed4300-ddd6-11db-8f34-0002a5d5c51b Error: -3
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2450)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2510)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot initialize effect engine for type: 0bed4300-ddd6-11db-8f34-0002a5d5c51b Error: -3
    at android.media.audiofx.AudioEffect.&lt;init&gt;(AudioEffect.java:411)
    at android.media.audiofx.Equalizer.&lt;init&gt;(Equalizer.java:139)
    at com.my.app.name.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403)
    ... 9 more
```

It occurs when I try to initialize equalizer like this:

```
Equalizer eq = new Equalizer(0, 0);
```

Although the equalizer class throws this Exception but why does it occur and how can it be fixed? This also occurs on few other devices. But works fine on Nexus and most devices.

Can someone give any ideas? I also have the following permission in my manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
```

Thanks !!

Comment: did you get a proper solution?

Comment: @brijeshkumar No man, i don't think I got one !!

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the reason is `EFFECT_TYPE_EQUALIZER`. Read this Util, I think it will be useful for you:

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever;
import android.media.audiofx.AudioEffect;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Build;

import com.marverenic.music.instances.Song;
import com.marverenic.music.player.PlayerController;

import java.util.UUID;

import timber.log.Timber;

import static android.content.Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE;

public final class Util {

    /**
     * This UUID corresponds to the UUID of an Equalizer Audio Effect. It has been copied from
     * {@link AudioEffect#EFFECT_TYPE_EQUALIZER} for backwards compatibility since this field was
     * added in API level 18.
     */
    private static final UUID EQUALIZER_UUID;

    static {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
            EQUALIZER_UUID = AudioEffect.EFFECT_TYPE_EQUALIZER;
        } else {
            EQUALIZER_UUID = UUID.fromString("0bed4300-ddd6-11db-8f34-0002a5d5c51b");
        }
    }

    /**
     * This class is never instantiated
     */
    private Util() {

    }

    /**
     * Checks whether the device is in a state where we're able to access the internet. If the
     * device is not connected to the internet, this will return {@code false}. If the device is
     * only connected to a mobile network, this will return {@code allowMobileNetwork}. If the
     * device is connected to an active WiFi network, this will return {@code true.}
     * @param context A context used to check the current network status
     * @param allowMobileNetwork Whether or not the user allows the application to use mobile
     *                           data. This is an internal implementation that is not enforced
     *                           by the system, but is exposed to the user in our app's settings.
     * @return Whether network calls should happen in the current connection state or not
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("SimplifiableIfStatement")
    public static boolean canAccessInternet(Context context, boolean allowMobileNetwork) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager;
        connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo info = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (info == null) {
            // No network connections are active
            return false;
        } else if (!info.isAvailable() || info.isRoaming()) {
            // The network isn't active, or is a roaming network
            return false;
        } else if (info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
            // If it's a mobile network, return the user preference
            return allowMobileNetwork;
        } else {
            // The network is a wifi network
            return true;
        }
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    public static boolean hasPermission(Context context, String permission) {
        return context.checkSelfPermission(permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    public static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
        for (String permission : permissions) {
            if (!hasPermission(context, permission)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static Intent getSystemEqIntent(Context c) {
        Intent systemEq = new Intent(AudioEffect.ACTION_DISPLAY_AUDIO_EFFECT_CONTROL_PANEL);
        systemEq.putExtra(AudioEffect.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME, c.getPackageName());
        systemEq.putExtra(AudioEffect.EXTRA_AUDIO_SESSION, PlayerController.getAudioSessionId());

        ActivityInfo info = systemEq.resolveActivityInfo(c.getPackageManager(), 0);
        if (info != null && !info.name.startsWith("com.android.musicfx")) {
            return systemEq;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Checks whether the current device is capable of instantiating and using an
     * {@link android.media.audiofx.Equalizer}
     * @return True if an Equalizer may be used at runtime
     */
    public static boolean hasEqualizer() {
        for (AudioEffect.Descriptor effect : AudioEffect.queryEffects()) {
            if (EQUALIZER_UUID.equals(effect.type)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static Bitmap fetchFullArt(Song song) {
        if (song == null) {
            return null;
        }

        MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();

        try {
            retriever.setDataSource(song.getLocation());
            byte[] stream = retriever.getEmbeddedPicture();
            if (stream != null) {
                return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(stream, 0, stream.length);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Timber.e(e, "Failed to load full song artwork");
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The global audio session 0 is deprecated and can cause problems if you pass it to the Equalizer. See details in the doc https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Equalizer

To get rid the above-mentioned error just use a specific audio session id. Quick example:

Equalizer equalizer = new Equalizer(0, new MediaPlayer().getAudioSessionId());